# How to compile ng-include html file in a variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

i'm storing a html string in a scope object and want to pass it to a variable

```
  $scope.template1 = "div ng-include="'/app.html'" </div>"
```

Then i want to pass this template1 to my bootstrap template option with the output of $scope.template1

```
 tour.start{
  template:$scope.template1// Here i'm looking the output with the content of app.html
  }
```

How can i compile template1 and pass the output?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service:

```
$scope.template1 = $compile("div ng-include="'/app.html'" </div>")($scope);
```

This way, your template will contain your ng-include content
(remember to add $compile to your dependencies).

By the way, I recommend that you use $templateCache service to store your static content in javascript, in order to have a unique place (and optimized too!) to store your templates:

```
app.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('app.html', '<span> app.html content </span>');
});
```

and your ng-include will find *automagically* your app.html template.
You should do this also for your `template1` variable, and retrieve it in your JS by using:

```
$templateCache.get('template1.html')
```

Comment: I did that already but i'm not getting the entire output. I'm getting an array as [COMMENT], and inside the array i don't see any output though

Comment: your ""div ng-include="'/app.html' has a opening bracket  <, right?

Comment: Nothing to do with the syntax $scope.template1 = $compile("<div ng-include="'/app.html'" </div>")($scope);

Comment: Maybe /app.html it's in another url? you should provide more code: by here i can make only assumptions

Comment: I created a  sample plunker,  bear me if there are some mistakes in it   https://plnkr.co/edit/y1ooATcxQBA7la9Q3lzi?p=preview